# Can I modify build.gradle on dependent project?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm converting a large Android project from Eclipse to Android Studio.

Currently we have unencrypted keys and certificates in configuration files and folders, grouped by "flavors". We have several Java Ant tasks to obfuscate or encrypt the keys and certificates and then Ant tasks to replace tokens in a Java template file with the Base64 encoded keys and certs.

I moved the configuration properties from text files to buildConfigFields in gradle files. I also plan to move the keys and the certificate file names to buildConfigFields in product flavors and convert the Java Ant tasks to simple Java code to run with JavaExec from a separate Gradle project.

But I also want to use the Base64 encoded keys and certs from gradle.build flavors with buildConfigFields, if possible. So is it possible to modify a build.gradle file on a dependent project? Or should I modify the Java files, like in Eclipse? Or put the encoded keys and certs in string files?

Comment: Obviously Base64 is applied after obfuscation or proper encryption. It's just for the transport layer.

Comment: Ah, sorry that wasn't clear - thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by _"modify a `build.gradle` file on a dependent project"_? Do you mean having the root build script inject configuration to the sub-project build scripts or modify the build scripts files themselves?

Comment: No, there is a Java subproject, and it's only task is to obfuscate and encrypt the keys. I would like to inject the results for the main projects build.gradle file.